# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Tags: java

I get the message in the title when I try to use this method, but I can't find out why. Anyone who can help me?

Thanks!

```
void companyInfo() {
    int tel = 0;
    System.out.print("Name of company: ");
    String tmpCompany = sc.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < tel; i++){
        if (tmpCompany.equals(null)){
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < field.length; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < field[k].length; k++){
                if (tmpCompany != (null) && field[i][j] != 0 && tmpCompany.equals(felt[i][j])){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (tmpCompany != null && count > 0) {
            System.out.print("The company " + tmpCompany + " owns " + count + " field(s).");
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: Can you post stacktrace?? And where is the array declared? Show us.

Comment: What is the point of the `tel` variable and the first for-loop? The loop never executes its body.

Comment: The reason this site doesn't get fifty posts like this every second is  because you can step through the program (using an IDE) to easily see exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, what's in your arrays since I see a line like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < field[k].length; k++)
```

field[k]. But you get the error because you try to find index 10 in an array that is a length lower than 10.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for (int k = 0; k < field[k].length; k++)
```

should almost certainly be:

```
for (int k = 0; k < field[j].length; k++)
```

Although you're *then* using `field[i][j]` within the body of the loop, which seems unlikely to be what you want. I note that you're not using `k` at all within the loop. It's unclear why you think you need three levels of looping when you've only got a 2-dimensional array<sup>1</sup>.

Basically, you should revisit your loop bounds and *every* access of `field`, by the looks of it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know it's really just an array of arrays. The point is that it's not an array of arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` condition, shouldn't it be `field[j][k]` as below:

```
 if (tmpCompany != (null) && field[j][k] != 0 && tmpCompany.equals(field[j][k])){
```